# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Artificial Intelligence over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3          6
Users destroyed³                                  1          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   9          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue           300        604
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue               17         49
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         65         99
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               64        127
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue               666      1,284
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue              684        744
Tags merged                                      14          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             9          0
Tag synonyms created                             10          0
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions unprotected                             0          2
Questions reopened                               19          0
Questions protected                               1         38
Questions migrated                               47          0
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁵                                2        534
Questions closed                                215         65
Question flags handled⁵                         273        263
Posts unlocked                                    0         11
Posts undeleted                                  10         45
Posts locked                                      1        101
Posts deleted⁶                                  213        899
Posts bumped                                      0        910
Comments undeleted                                9          0
Comments flagged                                  1      1,362
Comments deleted⁷                             1,567      1,116
Comment flags handled                         1,223        140
Answers flagged                                   4        502
Answer flags handled                            384        122
All comments on a post moved to chat              5          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Some metrics (that probably needed to be improved) have improved, such as the number of comments flagged. It would be easier if you could provide an automatic way of visualizing these metrics and their evolution throughout the years.