# My answer was deleted by a diamond moderator to gain votes and answer for himself

Tags: discussion, support, bug, moderators

###### Raising concern here as Flags and request for moderator intervention has failed. Requesting intervention of AI staff moderators.

Is it general norms that a diamond moderator [**nbro**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)(https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)  can misuse his powers to delete another user's answer to gain reputation for himself?

**It has come to my notice my answer was copied into this site by the diamond moderator [**nbro**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)**,
which was already addressed on Nov 25 (
[Are there any resources that introduce the basics of online machine learning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32415/are-there-any-resources-that-introduce-the-basics-of-online-machine-learning/33920#33920))

If my answer wasn't plagiarised by diamond moderator nbro, the right thing to do NOT DELETE or keep seeking reasons to delete my posts and answers.

COPIED ANSWER SCREENSHOT
[image]

Comment: "It has come to my notice my answer was copied into this site by the diamond moderator nbro"

Which answer did he supposedly copy from which other answer by you? I looked at his answer, including all previous revisions of it, and they seem completely different from yours.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your **wrong assumption** (and, in my view, absurd accusation) that I copied from you. I did not copy your answer, which I didn't even know existed.

As I wrote under your answer (which you just copied and pasted from Data Science SE), which was actually plagiarised from external sources (2 external websites)

> Note that I didn't even know that your answer existed on another site. I didn't even know that this question had also been asked on Data Science. So, I didn't copy from your answer, so I didn't plagiarise you, as you're attempting to demonstrate (with your flagging). In addition to that, you're not the author of those papers. Even if I had read your answer on the other site (which did not happen, again!), my answer is completely different from yours. Plagiarism happens you copy and paste and don't give proper attribution, which is not the case at all.

The craziest thing is that you're accusing me of plagiarizing you when there's no evidence, while, in reality, you copied from external sources and you didn't give proper attribution, i.e. you plagiarised, which can be subject to suspension. In particular, in your original answer, you copied from [this site](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/32818/online-machine-learning) and [this site](https://vowpalwabbit.org/).

Having said that, losing 10+15=25 reputation points (which are the points that you gain by getting an answer upvoted once and accepted, which is the case with my answer that you're mentioning) doesn't change much for me. I've been contributing to this site for a long time and I only want that this site provides high-quality content, which is not plagiarised. [Plagiarised content will be deleted](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), which was the case with your partially plagiarised answer.

In addition to that, cross-posted content is sometimes discouraged on SE sites, so we may just delete that post, given an answer was already given somewhere else. However, I don't think that's necessary (because cross-posting is not forbidden, but just discouraged) and this issue is orthogonal to your absurd accusation.