# Answer deleted by diamond moderator during bounty

Tags: discussion, support, bug, moderators, moderation

###### Raising concern here as Flags and request for moderator intervention has failed. Requesting intervention of AI staff moderators.

Is it general norms that a **diamond moderator[nbro](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)** can delete an answer to prevent a user from helping others or getting bounty points for their efforts?

It has come to my attention my answer was deleted, without cause [Why is gradient descent used over the conjugate gradient method?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32428/why-is-gradient-descent-used-over-the-conjugate-gradient-method/32559#32559)

Kindly provide an explanation!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> Is it general norms that a diamond moderator nbro can **delete an answer to prevent a user from helping others or getting bounty points for their efforts**?

No, those reasons as highlighted in bold would not be valid reasons for deletion. There is no indication that these were actually the reasons for deletion in this case though.

> It has come to my attention my answer was deleted, **without cause**

It was not without cause. The reason for deletion (plagiarism, which is a valid reason) was already pointed out by nbro in a comment shortly before/after deletion, and if I'm not mistaken you as author of the original post should still be able to read that even though it was deleted since (just like how you can still read the post itself).

Answer (score 2):

This answer was deleted because you copied content from a paper without clarifying which parts you copied, so you basically tried to make it seem that the content in that answer was yours, while, in reality, you copied many things (if not everything) from that paper, i.e. plagiarism.

Plagiarised content, as I explain in [my other answer](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2836/2444), is subject to deletion. People that plagiarise can also be suspended, so, please, avoid doing this next time. Do not copy and paste content from external sources without clearly explaining which parts were taken from the external source.

If you don't know how to quote certain parts from an external source, take a look at this: [How to reference material written by others](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Moreover, ideally, you should not just quote an excerpt from a paper, but you should explain with your own words.

Having said that, if you're not familiar with the topic, I would recommend that you do not attempt to provide an answer, in order to avoid spreading misinformation or misunderstandings. However, this is just my personal suggestion.